# Signature validation failed for SAML Response

Tags: java, adfs2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have configured ADFS with Identity Server. I have a signed certificate from ADFS which is imported into Identity Server. I have also changed the IdpAlias property appropriately. However, I am getting following error, while using travelocity.com appliction.

SEVERE: An error has occurred
org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.exception.SSOAgentException: Signature validation failed for SAML Response
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.validateSignature(SAML2SSOManager.java:483)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.processSSOResponse(SAML2SSOManager.java:227)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.processResponse(SAML2SSOManager.java:145)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentFilter.doFilter(SSOAgentFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 01, 2016 11:34:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/travelocity.com] threw exception [Signature validation failed for SAML Response] with root cause
org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.exception.SSOAgentException: Signature validation failed for SAML Response
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.validateSignature(SAML2SSOManager.java:483)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.processSSOResponse(SAML2SSOManager.java:227)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.processResponse(SAML2SSOManager.java:145)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SSOAgentFilter.doFilter(SSOAgentFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, ADFS sends the response to Identity Server where it signs the response with it's private key. Then Identity Server validates the response from the public certificate that you have entered in the IDP configuration.

Then what happens is, Identity Server creates it's own SAML respnose and sends to travelocity application. In the Service Provider configuration, if you have enabled response signing, Identity Server signs the SAML response from it's private key.

For travelocity, you have to export the public certificate of Identity Server and import it to the keystore (wso2carbon.jks) file of travelocity application. Then in travelocity.properties file, you have to change the IDPCertAlias property giving the alias of the public certificate of Identity Server.

Then it should work.

Basically, travelocity does not know anything about ADFS. Only Identity Server knows it. travelocity knows only the Identity Server.

Comment: Perfect. That is the same thing I did and it worked. I could not post my reply. Thanks for posting here, again.